# Transliteration from Ukrainian to English

Tags: php, apostrophe, transliteration

I try to make translit function from Ukrainian to English on php. Is this correct especially for apostroph sign. And what about translit function from English to Ukrainian? Any ideas or link

```
function translit($s) {
    $s = (string) $s; 
    $s = trim($s);
    $s = strtr($s, array('зг'=>'zgh','а'=>'a','б'=>'b','в'=>'v','г'=>'h','ґ'=>'g','д'=>'d','е'=>'e','є'=>'ie','ж'=>'zh','з'=>'z','и'=>'y','і'=>'i','ї'=>'i','й'=>'i','к'=>'k','л'=>'l','м'=>'m','н'=>'n','о'=>'o','п'=>'p','р'=>'r','с'=>'s','т'=>'t','у'=>'u','ф'=>'f','х'=>'kh','ц'=>'ts','ч'=>'ch','ш'=>'sh','щ'=>'shch','ю'=>'iu','я'=>'ia','`'=>'','ь'=>'','Зг'=>'Zgh','А'=>'A','Б'=>'B','В'=>'V','Г'=>'H','Ґ'=>'G','Д'=>'D','Е'=>'E','Є'=>'Ye','Ж'=>'Zh','З'=>'Z','И'=>'Y','І'=>'I','Ї'=>'Yi','Й'=>'Y','К'=>'K','Л'=>'L','М'=>'M','Н'=>'N','О'=>'O','П'=>'P','Р'=>'R','С'=>'S','Т'=>'T','У'=>'U','Ф'=>'F','Х'=>'Kh','Ц'=>'Ts','Ч'=>'Ch','Ш'=>'Sh','Щ'=>'Shch','Ю'=>'Yu','Я'=>'Ya')); // згідно Паспорта (КМУ 2010) 
    return $s; // повертаємо результат
}
```

Not every apostrophe is removed from the text :(

Also I'm interesting in correct English to Ukrainian translitiration - if you have

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write your own logic or maintain your own database:

```
function translit($s) {
    return transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII', $s);
}
```

For `повертаємо результат` it produces `povertaemo rezul'tat`.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/g901Y) and [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php).

Comment: Sorry! But, your code incorrect - from "Іван Згурський" it make "Ivan Zgurs'kij". But by law (in international passport for example) must be "Ivan Zghurskii"

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with Ukrainian. Then "Any-Latin" is probably wrong and you need a set of rules that explicitly cover Ukrainian. I'll update the question if I'm able to find documentation about that.

Comment: I give in. ICU is a carrer path, not something you can master in one afternoon. You may want to try this library: [fre5h /
transliteration-php](https://github.com/fre5h/transliteration-php). It uses its own implementation rather than ICU data and it doesn't produce the single quote.